# VIM C++ Syntax Highlighting: Error detected while processing

Tags: c++, vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to enable advanced syntax highlighting when using VIM on a non-local machine. I'm using the plugin from here: https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight

I created the directory `/.vim/after/syntax/` and moved the cpp.vim file into it. When I open a .cpp file it gives me the following error:

[image: vim error]

What should I do?

Comment: Your .vim file looks like it was saved on Windows and have Windows line endings see ^M characters.

Comment: @MarekVitek I cloned the directory onto my computer (windows) and then transferred the files to the server (unix/mac not sure). What should I do?

Comment: You can try this command in vim `:%s/^M//g` where ^M you will get by pressing Ctrl+v Ctrl+m.  This way you should get rid of wrong line endings.

Comment: @MarekVitek thanks! I actually just did `:set ff=unix` and it did the trick. If you feel like typing up an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has DOS line endings. In order to get rid of them open your file and run following command:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

where ^M you will get by pressing Ctrl+v Ctrl+m.  This way you should get rid of wrong line endings.
Or just use `:set ff=unix` as you wrote.

There is also another option. You can also configure git to not convert line endings [dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)